# Power $k$ of a Jordan nilpotent block has ones on its upper diagonal of order $k+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $J$ be a Jordan nilpotent block $n\times n$. We know that $J^k$ is a matrix with diagonal in the $k+1$ place. How to prove it? I can show it for $k=2,3,\ldots,10$ times, but I need a general proof.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title. For example, "exponentiation" should be "power"...

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a nilpotent Jordan Block.

$$J=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ &0&1 \\ &&\ddots &\ddots \\ &&&0 &1 \\ &&&&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Let's take $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ the base in which we are considering this block.
We notice that $J(v_1)=0, J(v_2)=v_1, \dots ,J(v_n)=v_{n-1}$

Let's now consider $J^k$. You can easily conclude.